RabbitMQ Queue Renamed to name_skipped When Consuming with MassTransit
I am new to RabbitMQ and MassTransit. I have a RabbitMQ producer that successfully publishes messages to a queue named bot_notification_queue. However, when I start my consumer using MassTransit, the existing queue gets renamed to bot_notification_queue_skipped, and a new bot_notification_queue is created.
Producer Code:
public class BasicProducer : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConnectionFactory _factory;
    private readonly IConnection _connection;
    private readonly IModel _channel;
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private bool _disposed = false;

    public BasicProducer(ILogger logger, string hostName, string username, string password)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = hostName,
                UserName = username,
                Password = password
            };
            _connection = _factory.CreateConnection();
            _channel = _connection.CreateModel();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to create RabbitMQ connection and channel.");
            throw;
        }
    }

    public void PublishMessage<T>(T message, QueueOptions queueOptions)
    {
        try
        {
            DeclareQueue(queueOptions);

            var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message);
            var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);
            var properties = _channel.CreateBasicProperties();
            properties.Persistent = true;
            properties.ContentType = "application/json";

            _channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: queueOptions.Name, basicProperties: properties, body: body);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Failed to publish message to queue {queueOptions.Name}");
            throw;
        }
    }

    private void DeclareQueue(QueueOptions options)
    {
        _channel.QueueDeclare(queue: options.Name,
            durable: options.Durable,
            exclusive: options.Exclusive,
            autoDelete: options.AutoDelete,
            arguments: options.Arguments);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        try
        {
            if (!_disposed)
            {
                _channel?.Close();
                _connection?.Close();
                _channel?.Dispose();
                _connection?.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Failed to dispose RabbitMQ connection and channel.");
            throw;
        }
        _disposed = true;
    }
}
 

How the message produced:
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var producer = new BasicProducer(_logger, "localhost", "username", "passoword");

    var options = new QueueOptions("bot_notification_queue")
    {
        Durable = true,
        Arguments = null,
        Exclusive = false,
        AutoDelete = false,
    };

    var view = new PostNotificationViewModel
    {
        Message = "hello world",
        PhoneNumber = "test number",
    };

    producer.PublishMessage(view, options);

    Console.ReadLine();
}

Consumer Code:
builder.Services.AddMassTransit(busConfigurator =>
{
    busConfigurator.AddConsumer<BotNotificationMassConsumer>();
    busConfigurator.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
    busConfigurator.UsingRabbitMq((context, busFactoryConfigurator) =>
    {
        busFactoryConfigurator.Host("localhost", h =>
        {
            h.Username("username");
            h.Password("password");
        });

        busFactoryConfigurator.ReceiveEndpoint("bot_notification_queue", e =>
        {
            e.ConfigureConsumer<BotNotificationMassConsumer>(context);
        });
    });
}); 

I am using .net 8, RabbitMQ.Client version is 6.8.1,
MassTransit version is 8.2.3
MassTransit.RabbitMQ version is 8.2.3

Queues are not renamed, that isn't even possible in RabbitMQ. Consider this question to understand why message may be skipped.
